# Getting location of cross-project resources

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have read many similar questions where the reply is that the project structure is not ideal so my questions based on the following:

I have a main project (ProjA) which needs to include a second project (ProjB) which is not a child project. ProjB has various resource files which need to be copied in the distribution of ProjA.

**`build.gradle` of ProjA**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":ProjB")
}    

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "Something"
        contents {
            into('bin') { from jar.archivePath }
            into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }
            into('etc') {
                from ('../../projb/src/main/webapp') // Fix me!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1.) Ideally ProjB should expose the location of the resource files through a property used by ProjA, how can this be done?

2.) Is this the correct way to do it as I have read alot about cross-project properties not being ideal -  or should I be doing something completely different?

Comment: Is `war` plugin used in the second project?

Comment: Let me also know if your project is hosted online.

Comment: Not using war. It is a scala app in embedded jetty. The web related resources/framework are defined in ProjB which is reusable across multiple web server projects.

Comment: Just for clarification, the reason for not using sub-projects is that the common resources are used across departments with separate repositories for their specific sources.

Comment: Sure. I've asked about `war`, because it exposes such property. I've two ideas but just a little time to answer. Will do it this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it helps but it seems that the best way is to do it in the following way:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "Something"
        contents {
            into('bin') { from jar.archivePath }
            into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }
            into('etc') {
                from project(':projB').file('src/main/webapp')                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The path must be hardcoded in that case.

Second option might be specifying a project property - in general not a very good idea - and use in another project - *there must be also evaluation order defined*.

In **projB**

```
ext.resourcesDir = project.file('src/main/webapp2')
```

and in **projA**

```
evaluationDependsOn(':projB')
```

and:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "Something"
        contents {
            into('bin') { from jar.archivePath }
            into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }
            into('etc') {
                from project(':projB').file('src/main/webapp')                
                from project(':projB').resourcesDir
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28072698)'s complete example.